# how to store .bat file in azure, execute it and connect to it

Tags: azure

I'm new in windows azure but I already know how to deploy my service in azure. I need to have sth like a folder in azure to store some text files, two .exe files and one .bat file. then I want my deployed service to use these files and execute .bat file and create some new text files on that folder.

My question is if there is sth like the folder that I need?how to execute it? and how is it possible to connect to that folder through my wcf service?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Windows Azure PaaS? Or IaaS?  If PaaS, the VMs are stateless.  Everything written to the folders on the VM would be gone when you restart the instance or redeploy.  A solution can be suggested if you provide more information on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want Windows Azure PaaS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that bat file to execute one time i.e. during role start up, you can use [start up task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx). 
If you want to execute bat file during WCF call, you can use .NET [process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. However for executing this task, you may require higher privileges.